# Bash: Add value to associative array, while a key=>value already exists

Tags: bash, associative-array

How can i add a value to an existing key within an associative array?

```
declare -A DATA
DATA=([foo]="bar" [foo2]="bar2" [foo3]="bar3")
```

Should be something like

```
DATA=([foo]="bar text" [foo2]="bar" [foo3]="bar")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `+=`.

```
DATA[foo]+=" test"
```

This will add `foo` as a key if it doesn't already exist; if that's a problem, be sure to verify that `foo` is in fact a key first.

```
# bash 4.3 or later
[[ -v DATA[foo] ]] && DATA[foo]+=" test"

# A little messier in 4.2 or earlier; here's one way
( : ${DATA[foo]:?not set} ) 2> /dev/null && DATA[foo]+=" test"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the old value on the right hand side of the assignment.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A DATA
DATA=([foo]="bar" [foo2]="bar2" [foo3]="bar3")

DATA[foo]=${DATA[foo]}' text'
DATA[foo2]=${DATA[foo2]:0:-1}
DATA[foo3]=${DATA[foo3]:0:-1}

declare -p DATA
# DATA=([foo]="bar text" [foo2]="bar" [foo3]="bar")
```